# Error while using case with substring query while multiply with number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue while am trying to pull and create specific column output in SQL

```
select 
left(PostalCode,2) as area
,case substring(PostalCode,6,1) 
 when substring(PostalCode,6,1) = 0 then '100'
 when substring(PostalCode,6,1) > 0 then (substring(PostalCode,6,1))*100
 else 'NotDigit'
end + substring(PostalCode,6,1) as [location]
from province_table
```

| PostalCode |
| --- |
| 1K02BC19 |
| 1K03B018 |
| 1K04B519 |

I tried many ways to restructure the query above and am always unable to get a result

expected result

| Location |
| --- |
| NoDigit |
| 100 |
| 500 |

looking forwards to your kind help

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server doesn't let you do math with text. You have to manually convert it to a number type.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, how i will be able to do that?

Comment: by calling `CAST()` a lot, and paying very close attention to the exact data type of each part of every expression.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, appreciated the advice am not that familiar with how to use CAST()

Comment: That's something you should be able to look up.

Comment: I see a bunch of potential issues. can you post the table you're working with?

Comment: @DannySlor thanks for the follow up, below a sample of the table 

|PostalCode | 
| 1K02BC19 | 
| 1K03B018 | 
| 1K04B519 | 
` ` ` `

Comment: There are a two version of the `case` syntax and you have mixed them together. Delete `substring(PostalCode,6,1)` immediately following `case`, so it leaves just `case when ...`

Comment: @Bohemian, i did delete it and i received this error msg : Conversation failed when converting nvarchar value'_' to data type int.

Comment: @David see my answer. SQL server actually converts it to string for you automatically if it's a number in that context so you have to make sure it's a number with `isnumeric()` and then convert then result to `varchar` because you want to display `NotDigit` (you might as well leave it as an int and let it be `null` if it's not a number, but that's up to you).

Comment: I meant converts it to int of course... it's already a string...

Comment: @David all return types of a case must be the same: cast `substring(PostalCode,6,1))*100` to nvarchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
left(PostalCode,2) as area
,case when isnumeric(substring(PostalCode,6,1)) = 1 and substring(PostalCode,6,1) = 0 then cast('100' as varchar(max))
      when isnumeric(substring(PostalCode,6,1)) = 1 and substring(PostalCode,6,1) > 0 then cast(substring(PostalCode,6,1)*100 as varchar(max))
      else 'NotDigit' end as result
from province_table
```

| area | result |
| --- | --- |
| 1K | NotDigit |
| 1K | 100 |
| 1K | 500 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X47S8_fm)